# Read which file is another process using or reading which file is being used

Tags: java, file, process, output

I want to make a program that can see which file is being used...
For example, if I want to see which song is being played on the pc, reather in windows media player or some other software...
*How can I achieve this?*

I taught either read read some folder to see which file is being read by some process or to track a process to see which file is he reading and playing...

I would like to do everything in java but i don't know where to start...

Can someone give me some lead...

Comment: I found programs like Process Hacker with which you can "Find handles and DLLs" and if you search folder with the songs you will get path of the file being used from which you can see the song currently being played...that's how far i got, still searching for the full solution...